# 100,000 page renders using headless browser, max per cpu per second on aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, web-scraping, chromium

I'm doing a scraping project and need to use a browser to load javascript on websites that I visit.

If using just http I can get up to `150/second` on an `m4.large`. Which has `2 cpus`. On initial tests using headless chrome its so much slower around `4 / second` and typically the bottleneck is CPU not RAM. For many web pages basic http is fine but increasingly its not with single page apps etc.

Does anyone have some experience doing something similar? What were you able to achieve? What was the stack you used e.g. `python, selenium, headless chrome and multiprocessing`. Did you have to alter the configuration of chrome?

Comment: Is your goal to _download_ or to _execute_ the javascript?

Comment: This is where my knowledge starts to waiver, I basically just want the DOM but for sites that use stuff like react, what I get from basic http is totally different from when I load the page using a browser or when I use basic http. I guess download?

Comment: A simple HTTP GET isn't a "headless browser" it's just a raw file download, and your 150/second number is just downloading 150 files per second, while a single webpage might actually be comprised of lots of files. If you want to scrape the actual rendered webpage as it would be displayed in a web browser then you have to use a headless browser. The http get requires almost no server resources and will be as fast as your network connection can handle. Rendering in a headless browser is going to use lots of server resources (CPU/RAM) as you have noticed, and it's going to take much more time.

Comment: Mark B, if I changed the question title to "page renders" is that a better question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular page on Stack Overflow takes 1.2 seconds to load on my machine, according to the "Performance" tab in Chrome's devtools:

[image: Performance tab]

You can break that down by CPU usage or wall clock time, but the point is that it takes a while.

In this case I would load the page once in a browser to learn what resources are accessed, then execute those using a load testing tool other than a browser.

[image: Copy All as cURL]

Naively executing this curl command — first parallelizing it by replacing `;` with `&` — takes 1.8 seconds on my machine. But the point is that you only want to hit the server, not interpret any HTML, CSS, JavaScript, or images.

But if you want to *crawl* the web and see what really happens upon each page load, so that you can look at the page and decide where to go next, there isn't much to do besides a headless browser. Real production web crawlers have a much larger machine budget, and possibly use clever techniques to avoid wasting CPU on decoding images and laying out CSS.

Comment: Josh thanks for your response, "and possibly use clever techniques to avoid wasting CPU on decoding images and laying out CSS" thats what I'm wondering. Is it fair to say the "page render" is actually 91 (in your case) http gets? If so I wonder then if its possible to just download 91 pages rather than actually execute the javascript and such?

Comment: "page render" would include 91 http requests in that example.. it also includes javascript execution, building the DOM and rendering everything.